# How to Visit a Site in Cron and Follow HTML Meta Redirects

Tags: php, html, redirect, cron

Is there a way/tool to visit a site in cron that is capable of following HTML Meta Tag Redirects?

A programmer wrote a feature that when hit through a browser returns

```
<html>
      <head>
        <!-- HTML meta refresh URL redirection -->
        <meta http-equiv="refresh"
        content="0; url='.$base_url.'/cache/'.($trip_index+1).'">
      </head>
      <body>
        <p>The page has moved to:
        <a href="'.$base_url.'/cache/'.($trip_index+1).'">'.$base_url.'/cache/'.($trip_index+1).'</a></p>
      </body>
</html>';
```

In a browser that will take you from `example.com/cache/1` to `example.com/cache/2` automatically until all the steps are done. Then the client came back and also wanted it to be automated...

I can't use cURL even with the `-L` flag because it only follows redirects in headers like 301, not the HTML ones.

I then found out about `links` and that worked great from the CLI with something like `links -html-auto-refresh 1 example.com/cache` and finished to the end. But unfortunately it doesn't work in cron because the refresh is part of the rendering itself.

So is there a tool that will work from a cron task that will do this? Browser testing tools? Selenium? PhantomJS? Splash?

Comment: Yes, you could use (and are apparently already aware of) Selenium, PhantomJS, Chromium headless, etc.

Comment: Would you happen to know what's the best/possible way to solve it Selenium? I've only used it for testing, so unsure of how to bend it to this use case.